# Inequality - Normal Distribuion

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

I have the next inequality that I need to prove:
If $X$ has a Normal $(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ distribution.
$$P(|X-\mu|>\varepsilon\space\sigma)\le \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}e^{\frac{-\varepsilon^2}{2}} $$

My approach: This looks like the Chebyshev's inequality; so I just opened the value of the absolute value, however I got stock:

$$P(|X-\mu|)>\varepsilon\space\sigma = P(-\varepsilon>\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}>\varepsilon)=P(|Z|>\varepsilon)$$

Where $Z$ is defined for the usual Normal distribution as $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$

Any ideas.. tips.. are welcomed

Answer (score 1):

For every positive $z$, $P[|Z|\gt z]=2P[Z\gt z]$ and
$$
\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot P[Z\gt z]=\int_z^\infty\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\mathrm dt\leqslant\int_z^\infty\frac{t}z\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\mathrm dt=\frac1z\mathrm e^{-z^2/2}.
$$